# Best way to query in firebase for multiple fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firestore users collection scheme

```
@collection
"users":
{ 
   [
   ...
   "geopoint": {lat:37, long:45},
   "age": 45,
   "skills":["Programmer", "Architecture", "Biker"],
   "gender": "male"
   ...
   ],
   [
   ...
   "geopoint": {lat:47, long:44},
   "age": 24,
   "skills":["Programmer", "Biker", "Painter"],
   "gender": "femail"
   ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

is there an effective way to query on all these fields without losing performance?

example query I'm trying to execute in dart:

```
    final users = await store.collection('users')
        .where('geopoint.hash',
            isLessThan: filter.geopointHighHash,
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                filter.geopointLowHash)
        .where('age', isLessThan: filter.endAge, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: filter.startAge,)
        .where('skills', arrayContainsAny: filter.skills)
        .where('gender', isEqualTo: filter.gender)
        .get();
```

but this query fails due to [firestore limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)
`In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.`

Comment: @Dharmaraj This query will not be executed bc it has 2 inequality filters see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use inequality filters on 2 different fields but here's a workaround which will work to some extent as intended. You can use `>=` and `<=` operators on `geopoint` fields and then use the `in` operator for filtering by `age`. Although as `in` operators allow only 10 items in it so you would have to batch your request.

```dart
final users = await store.collection('users')
   .where('geopoint.hash',
     isLessThan: filter.geopointHighHash,
     isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: filter.geopointLowHash)
   .where('age', whereIn: [filter.startAge, filter.startAge+1, ..., filter.startAge + 9])
   //.where('skills', arrayContainsAny: filter.skills)
   .where('gender', isEqualTo: filter.gender)
   .get();
```

For example if the `startAge` is set to 12, then this query will return all docs with ages 12 to 21. Similarly make another request for 22 to 31 and so on.

Here's another catch, you cannot use `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` in a single request so you would have to manually filter skills on client side.
But I think if skills are more relevant then you should remove the `age` field from your query and then manually filter out documents with ages out of selected range.

Either way you need to filter one field on client side for the time being so go add the field which is more relevant to the query (or whichever will return less number of irrelevant documents).